# Programmatically restarting Azure virtual machine generates 404 error

Tags: azure

I'm attempting to reboot/restart an Azure virtual machine through the [REST interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157197.aspx).

I created a virtual machine through the Azure portal and it appears as running under the Virtual Machines tab on the left.

The url I am using for this operation is as follows:

https://management.core.windows.net/**{my-subscription-guid}**/services/hostedservices/**cloudvm-test**/deployments/**cloudvm-test**/roles/**cloudvm-test**/Operations

You can see "cloudvm-test" repeated as the hosted service name, the deployment name and the role name because that's how it appears in the xml you get back from calling [Get Hosted Service Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460806.aspx).  Even though a Virtual Machine is not a classic hosted service, it appears in this xml and so I just use the values I find there.  One of the concerns I have is whether I'm building the URL correctly.

Anyway, using the above URL, I build my request as expected, and POST a body of:

```
<RestartRoleOperation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<OperationType>RestartRoleOperation</OperationType></RestartRoleOperation>
```

The error I receive is a 404, stating that "The resource service name hostedservices is not supported".

Not that it really matters, but I'm writing in Objective C.  If you have an example in C# I can deal with it fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.../roles/roleName/...` you have to use `.../roleInstances/roleName ....` (replace **roles** with **roleInstances** in the Uri path).

The VM related documentation is full of such small mistakes.

By the way, in order to have a Virtual Machine you need to have a "Hosted Service". So if you try the REST API to create a VM, you will discover that you have to specify an existing hosted service. So you first have to create the Hosted service, and then deploy a Virtual Machine to it. It is a little confusing, because the portal hides that little detail from us. But if you go to the old portal you will see that there is actually a hosted service behind each Virtual VM you created. That hosted service does not appear in the new portal as "Cloud Service" until you delete all the VMs in it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That appears to do the trick, although I'm getting an HTTP 202 response (Accepted) instead of the documented HTTP 201 (Created).  I guess I'll chalk it up to another doc error.

Comment: I did some VM work recently (working on [fluent-management](https://github.com/richorama/fluent-management)) and frankly I don't think I've seen 201. All the answers were 202 Accepted. Even for CreateVirtualMachineDeployment! Plus, this also appears to be some inconsistency in docmentation - ResartRoleOperation cannot (semantically) return "Created". It is really semantically correct to return "Accepted".